# BER encode a string in go for LDAP userCertificate;binary

Tags: go, encoding, ldap, ber

I'm currently trying to build an simple LDAP server using https://github.com/nmcclain/ldap to serve mail clients (primarily Outlook) with an address book containing S/MIME Certificates.

So far the part regarding the "normal" LDAP attributes like `sn`, `mail`, `displayName` etc. work, but I struggle to get `userCertificate;binary` to work.

Using the ldap-debugger from https://github.com/pingidentity/ldapsdk/releases all looks good compared to a reference MS AD Server. I get the same response

Example from an AD:

```
LDAP Message:
 Message ID:  785
 Search Request Protocol Op:
      Base DN:  CN=user,OU=adresses,DC=local,DC=org
      Scope:  BASE
      Dereference Policy:  ALWAYS
      Size Limit:  100
      Time Limit:  100
      Types Only:  false
      Filter:  (objectClass=*)
      Requested Attributes:
           cn
           commonName
           mail
           roleOccupant
           display-name
           displayname
           sn
           surname
           co
           organizationName
           o
           givenName
           legacyExchangeDN
           objectClass
           uid
           mailNickname
           title
           company
           physicalDeliveryOfficeName
           telephoneNumber
           otherTelephone
           otherHomePhone
           info
           userCertificate;binary
           user-cert;binary
           userSMIMECertificate;binary
           TextEncodedORaddress
           otherMailbox
           proxyAddresses
           msExchHomeServerName
           secretary
           Telephone-Assistant
           Telephone-Office2
           ou
           organizationalUnitName
           department
           l
           postalCode
           st
           postalAddress
           streetAddress
           homephone
           initials
           mobile
           facsimileTelephoneNumber
           pager

[07/March/2022:13:08:10 +0100] conn=6 from="0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56415" to="0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:33389"
LDAP Message:
     Message ID:  785
     Search Result Entry Protocol Op:
          dn: CN=user,OU=adresses,DC=local,DC=org
          objectClass: top
          objectClass: person
          objectClass: organizationalPerson
          objectClass: user
          cn: user
          displayName: user
          sn: user
          company: company
          mail: user@company.org
          givenName: user
          userCertificate;binary:: MIIIvz...H5z/w7QDTxupw=
```

Example from my LDAP Server:

```
LDAP Message:
     Message ID:  648
     Search Request Protocol Op:
          Base DN:  CN=user,OU=adresses,DC=local,DC=org
          Scope:  BASE
          Dereference Policy:  ALWAYS
          Size Limit:  100
          Time Limit:  100
          Types Only:  false
          Filter:  (objectClass=*)
          Requested Attributes:
               cn
               commonName
               mail
               roleOccupant
               display-name
               displayname
               sn
               surname
               co
               organizationName
               o
               givenName
               legacyExchangeDN
               objectClass
               uid
               mailNickname
               title
               company
               physicalDeliveryOfficeName
               telephoneNumber
               otherTelephone
               otherHomePhone
               info
               userCertificate;binary
               user-cert;binary
               userSMIMECertificate;binary
               TextEncodedORaddress
               otherMailbox
               proxyAddresses
               msExchHomeServerName
               secretary
               Telephone-Assistant
               Telephone-Office2
               ou
               organizationalUnitName
               department
               l
               postalCode
               st
               postalAddress
               streetAddress
               homephone
               initials
               mobile
               facsimileTelephoneNumber
               pager

[07/March/2022:11:42:11 +0100] conn=6 from="0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58508" to="0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:33389"
LDAP Message:
     Message ID:  648
     Search Result Entry Protocol Op:
          dn: CN=user,OU=adresses,DC=local,DC=org
          objectClass: top
          objectClass: person
          objectClass: organizationalPerson
          objectClass: user
          uid: 3
          cn: user
          displayName: user
          sn: user
          company: user
          mail: user@test.com
          givenName: user@test.com
          userCertificate;binary: MIIIfzCC...VLjPjJlyMMA==
```

However, I don't see the userCertificate in Outlook.

The value of userCertificate is the result of

```
openssl x509 -in user_public_cert.cer -inform DER
```

minus the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" line as mentioned here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/431944/problems-with-ldap-usercertificate-attribute
This results in a base64 encoded string of the certificate.

However, if a capture the network traffic using Wireshark I get a clean decoded certificate with the MS AD Server and a "BER Error: Wrong field in SEQUENCE: expected class:UNIVERSAL(0) tag:16(SEQUENCE) but found class:APPLICATION(1) tag:9" to my server.

As far as I can tell DER should be a subset of BER that's why I assumed the openssl result should be enough.

Now I think I have to encode the base64 string again in BER. If this is right, how would I go about doing that?

The ldap.EntryAttribute looks currently like this

```
&ldap.EntryAttribute{"userCertificate;binary", []string{cert}},
```

where `cert` is a `string` from the database.